# Does order matter in poker hand draws?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm confused about the role of order in poker hand draws. Suppose we want to count the number of 5 card hands containing all 4 aces. Following the normal route for this problem we say we can choose all four aces in $$\binom{4}{4}$$ ways and then we can choose one remaining card in $$\binom{48}{1}$$ ways.

Now here is my confusion, this is unordered correct? The reason I think it is unordered is that if we were asked to calculate the probability we would divide by $$\binom{52}{5}$$ which is an unordered set.

However, the product of two binomial coefficients seems to be ordered because of the product rule of counting. The only difference I can see that would make the numerator unordered is that the two events are dependent. What is going on here?

Is the product of independent events ordered and the product of dependent events unordered?

Comment: The top is unordered. We don't ever say in which way the cards are lined up, only that we drew all four aces and one other card. A product of two binomial coefficients usually will not give you an ordered count.

Comment: You can, if you want, get the same correct probability by viewing the hands as ordered 5-tuples. Both the numerator and denominator will get multiplied by 5! (details left to you).